# sorting numbers using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, python-3.x

The purpous of using recursion instead of using `for i in range(11):` is because its advantagous to start from the top trying to solve a specific mathematical problem. The function will be changed so that it only returns `[n]`that matches certain criteria.

`print(numbers)=[[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]` Why is there extra brackets?
`print(numbers[7])=IndexError: list index out of range` Has this anything to do with the extra brackets?

```
# A function that is supposed to help sorting numbers in a list
def sorting_numbers(n):
    if n > 1:
        return [n] + sorting_numbers(n-1)
    else:
        return [1]

numbers = []
n = 10
numbers = (sorting_numbers(n))
print(numbers)
```

`print(numbers)=[[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]` Why is there extra brackets?
`print(numbers[7])=IndexError: list index out of range` Has this anything to do with the extra brackets?

Comment: "So that it only returns [n] that matches certain criteria" use a list comprehension for this. There really isn't any advantage in using recursion for this problem.

Comment: If you have further questions, please post them as separate questions. You keep deleting / undeleting / editing and changing the scope of the question every time, that's not how SO works. And regarding the last question: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8177274/201359) to see how to increment the recursion limit - but _really_ that's not the solution, the solution is avoiding the use of recursion

Comment: Did you _read_ the answer? the correct way to use `sorting_numbers` is: `numbers = storing_numbers(10)`, don't use `append`!

Comment: Ok i will not change the question next time. I´m sorry. I will post new questions instead. Thank you for your time. It helped me alot. I did read it and tried it out. I missed to remove append. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you *really* want to use recursion for such a simple problem - be warned that it's terribly inefficient and it will cause a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error for values of `n` close to `1000` (Python was not designed to handle recursion efficiently):

```
def storing_numbers(n):
    if n > 1:
        return [n] + storing_numbers(n-1)
    else:
        return [1]
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
def storing_numbers(n):
    return [] if n <= 0 else [n] + storing_numbers(n-1)
```

Notice how we build the list along the way, and that the base case also returns a list. Use it like this:

```
numbers = storing_numbers(10)
numbers
=> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Of course, it'd be unrealistic to use a recursive function for building a list for anything beyond an academic exercise. A real-life, practical implementation would do this instead:

```
list(range(10, 0, -1))
=> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

And here's how you'd use a list comprehension for filtering numbers matching a certain criteria, let's say, only even numbers:

```
[x for x in range(10, 0, -1) if x % 2 == 0]
=> [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a recursive call, you're returning a tuple: `(number, recursive_result)`. Thus, each time you recurse, you embed another layer of tuples into your final result.

It looks like your intention was just to sum the numbers from `1` to the input number, so all you have to do to fix it is change line 3 to return the result of the recursive call **plus** the original number, rather than just returning them both outright.

```
def function(number):
    if number > 1:
        # return the recursive result added to the original number
        return number + function(number-1) 
    else:
        return number
```

As a side note, you ought to give your function a more descriptive name, so that its purpose is clear!