# RuntimeError (maximum recursion depth exceeded) on working copy checkin

Tags: python, plone, versioning, zope, zodb

Plone 4.2.5 with collective.cover 1.0a11 installed; after trying to make the checkin of a working copy, the following error is shown:

```py
2016-01-28T21:22:11 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1454023331.870.405599566554 http://www.example.com/copy_of_frontpage/@@content-checkin
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.iterate.browser.checkin, line 50, in __call__
  Module plone.app.stagingbehavior.policy, line 56, in checkin
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module plone.app.iterate.subscribers.versioning, line 36, in handleAfterCheckin
  Module plone.app.iterate.archiver, line 43, in save
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 305, in save
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 450, in _recursiveSave
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ArchivistTool, line 265, in prepare
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ModifierRegistryTool, line 143, in getReferencedAttributes
  Module plone.app.versioningbehavior.modifiers, line 108, in getReferencedAttributes
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 366, in retrieve
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 499, in _retrieve
  Module Products.CMFEditions.CopyModifyMergeRepositoryTool, line 558, in _recursiveRetrieve
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ArchivistTool, line 340, in retrieve
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ArchivistTool, line 495, in __getitem__
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ZVCStorageTool, line 1027, in __getitem__
  Module Products.CMFEditions.ZVCStorageTool, line 265, in retrieve
  Module Products.ZopeVersionControl.Repository, line 463, in getVersionOfResource
  Module Products.ZopeVersionControl.Version, line 103, in copyState
  Module Products.ZopeVersionControl.Version, line 112, in stateCopy
  Module Products.ZopeVersionControl.Version, line 60, in cloneByPickle
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 865, in setstate
  Module logging, line 1174, in error
  Module logging, line 1266, in _log
  Module logging, line 1240, in makeRecord
  Module logging, line 263, in __init__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I upgraded the following packages but problem persisted:

```
plone.app.iterate = 2.1.14
plone.app.stagingbehavior = 0.1
plone.app.versioningbehavior = 1.1.4
Products.CMFEditions = 2.2.18
```

any hints?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue is related with the following bugs:

- https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFEditions/issues/28
- https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/issues/532

We created a new collective.cover object, populate it, deleted the old one, and now the checkout/checkin is working without issues.