# The faculty of two numbers python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def choose (x, y):
     if y > x: 
        print ("False")
     elif y == 0 or y == x: 
        return 1
     elif y == 1:
        return x
     else:
        if (x-y) > y:
            biggest = x-y
            smallest = y
        else:
            biggest = y
            smallest = x-y
       resultatet = x * choose (x-1, biggest) 
    res = resultatet // smallest
    return res
```

My function is working perfectly with whatever x input I insert but with bigger Y inputs like 8000 for example I'm getting

```
  File "/home/nazel607/labb3b_2.py", line 20, in choose
resultatet = x * choose (x-1, biggest) 
  File "/home/nazel607/labb3b_2.py", line 3, in choose
if y > x: 
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Is there a way I can overcome this problem or is it impossible in python due to its limits? Is there another way than increasing the limit?

Comment: Hi. Are you interested in finding a different way to calculate this value? Or do you want to know how to implement this specific algorithm, without coming up against this limitation?

Comment: @jwg Hi, I'm more interested in finding a way to use this specific algorithm and overcome the problem of limitation

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded)

Comment: @DavidG It is correct in my file but I'm not 100% sure if it got correct here when I copied the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can get rid of the recursion:

```
def choose2(x, y):
    if y > x:
        raise ValueError()

    if y == 0 or y == x:
        return 1

    if y == 1:
        return x

    result = 1
    while y != x:
        big, small = max(x-y, y), min(x-y, y)
        result *= x // small
        x -= 1
        y = big
    return result
```

I've tested it over few examples:

```
for x, y in [
    (4, 2),
    (17, 9),
    (125, 79),
    (8005, 13),
    (9005, 13),
    # (19005, 7004)  # exceeds max recursion depth on my machine
]:
    assert choose(x, y) == choose2(x, y)
```

and seems to work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You are not exiting the program ...

```
def choose (x, y):
    if y > x: 
        print ("False")
        return
    # ...rest of your program
```

Comment: You are right but i'm getting the exact same problem even after editing

Comment: Python is preventing you from recursing too deep. Check out `https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit`. Python doesn't do tail recursion