# Python RecursionError : Simple operation crashes with Pandas.eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, eval, numexpr

I have just read and drooled with excitement over [these newly found optimization functions](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html) for my `Pandas` related needs. According to this book :

> The DataFrame.eval() method allows much more succinct evaluation of expressions with the columns:

```
result3 = df.eval('(A + B) / (C - 1)') 
np.allclose(result1, result3)
```

> True

To my example :

My dataframe contains around 42000 records and 28 columns. Two of which are `Date` and `Heure` which are strings.

My goal : to concatenate both columns into one. Which I can easily do with this piece of code : `df_exade_light["Date"]+df_exade_light["Heure"]`, applying a  `%timeit` on it returns

> 6.07 ms ± 219 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

But for some reason `df.eval('Date + Heure')` returns a :

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

What's more, I apply the solution found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded) to raise the allowed stack depth, but the kernel just crashes.

What's the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

---

The problem can be reproduce with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X','Y'],
                   'B': ['U','V']})

df.eval('A+B')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your reproductible example is that you have **string**. In the link you give about [High-Performance Pandas: eval() and query()](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html), all examples are with **float** (or int).

One way to make it work with your example, is by using python as engine:

```
df.eval('A+B',engine='python')
```

By default, the engine used in `eval` is `'numexpr'` according to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) and this engine use the library of the same name [NumExpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), which is a **Fast numerical expression evaluator for NumPy**. Although in the previous link, an example with string is presented, it is not with the operation **+**. If you do `df.eval('A==B')` it works, same with other comparison operators, but not `df.eval('A+B')`. You can find more information [there](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but for **string**, beside using `engine='python'` it seems limited.

Going back to your original problem with **date** and **time** type, not sure you can find a solution with the default engine ([see here for supported datatype](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#datatypes-supported-internally))

Comment: Thank you :) I did a `%timeit df_exade_light.eval('Date+Heure',engine='python')` and the result is `6.94 ms ± 309 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` so indeed it isn't faster