# Problem using Python 2.6.6 and scapy 2.3.3 in CentOS 6

Tags: python, scapy, centos6, python-2.6

I'm trying to use scapy 2.3.3 (that should work with Python 2.6.6) but I'm getting 'Execution RuntimeError' every time I try to import.
[Scapy versions from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taXvF.png)

This is how I'm importing the modules:

```
import resource, os, sys
filepath = '/home/filloy/scapy-2.3.1/scapy'
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(filepath))
from scapy import all
```

An this is the error:

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    sniff(prn=arp_monitor_callback, filter="arp", store=0)
NameError: name 'sniff' is not defined
```

I cannot change the python version since the machine has to run in that configurations. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded#8177274)  and other variants with no result.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first retry using 2.4.3

Comment: 2.4.3 doesn't support python 2.6.6 or 2.7.

Comment: It does work with modern 2.7