# Python error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Tags: python

I have this code which is basically flipping a coin and when it hits heads (1) it flips again until the probability of it keep flipping heads is lower than 0.1% or when it hits tails it start again.

```py
import numpy


def checkAgain(probability):
    if(probability >= 0.1):
        runCode()

def flipCoin(successes):
    rand = numpy.random.randint(2)
    if (rand == 1):
        # true
        successes += 1
        flipCoin(successes)
    else:
        probability = 50
        for i in range(successes):
            probability /= 2
        print(str(successes) + " " + str(probability) + "%")
        checkAgain(probability)

def runCode():
    successes = 0
    flipCoin(successes)

runCode()
```

But the code only works sometimes. `Most of the time I get this error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` I read online that this prevents "a stack overflow" but I have no idea how I can make the code run untill the probability is lower than 0.1

Comment: Why are you using recursion in your code when you don't need to?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use recursivity in python if you can do the same algorithm with a simple while or for loop

Comment: when you are calling runcode again you are setting sucess 0 again ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809402/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-object)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conceptual problem in this question. (I can be wrong about that).

Each flip is independent from the previous flip and the next, so what i would do instead is calculate a geometric distribution (probability of getting head until you get a tail) and then take the CDF at the 99% [watch this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Probably this is why you get:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

If you would like to continue doing so i think using a while loop can be a solution as others pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you get "tails" and start a new "experiment", the previous calls never return, they simply accumulate, possibly until the maximum recursion depth is reached.

The program terminates when it samples at least 9 consecutive "heads" (from `probability < 0.1`), and the expected number of trials until this condition is met is at least `2 ** (9 + 1) - 2 = 1022` (example calculation on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455568)).

The problem is that this number may be above the default stack depth (most likely ~1000; see [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)), which is why you're getting the error.

Like others have suggested, you can simply use an iterative approach:

```py
import numpy

successes = 0

while True:
    rand = numpy.random.randint(2)
    
    if rand == 1:
        successes += 1
    else:
        probability = 50
        for i in range(successes):
            probability /= 2
        print(str(successes) + " " + str(probability) + "%")
        
        if probability >= 0.1:
            successes = 0
        else:
            break
```

and can even further simplify the `else` condition, since `probability >= 0.1` can only happen when `successes < 9`:

```py
import numpy

successes = 0

while True:
    rand = numpy.random.randint(2)
    
    if rand == 1:
        successes += 1
    else:        
        probability = 50 / (2 ** successes)
        print(str(successes) + " " + str(probability) + "%")
        
        if successes < 9:
            assert probability >= 0.1
            successes = 0
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

In short, more recursions --> more memory usage.
Read more about the error and a simple case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948775/what-is-the-recursion-depth-and-why-is-set-to-a-fixed-limit).
You can do the same with loops easily as mentioned by Julien Sorin.